# Google App Engine Entity Relationship Annotations end up HTTP 500

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, datanucleus

I am creating a simple REST API via Google app engine. I have `Task` and `Project` objects. A `Project` can have one or more `Task`s. Here is some details about these data objects:

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date createdAt;

    // Section 1
    // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    // private List<Task> tasks;

    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Key id;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String longDescription;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date dueDate;
    private boolean completed;

    // Section 2
    // @ManyToOne
    // @JoinColumn(name = "id_project")
    // private Project project;

    // ...
}
```

The way I implemented the class above works fine (Section 1 and Section 2 are commented out). However, what I want to do is to relate `Task` objects to `Project`. Whenever I remove the comments above and activate Section 1 and Section 2 the errors below occur.

The error appears for Project operations

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /api/project. Reason:

    Could not initialize class com.aspect.todo.dao.EMFService
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.aspect.todo.dao.EMFService
    at com.aspect.todo.dao.Dao.getProjects(Dao.java:144)
    at com.aspect.todo.server.ProjectService.get(ProjectService.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    ...
```

The error appears for Task operations

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /api/task. Reason:

    INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Caused by:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.aspect.todo.dao.Dao.getTasks(Dao.java:98)
    at com.aspect.todo.server.TaskService.get(TaskService.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ...


Caused by:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Provider error. Provider: org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:176)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:112)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:66
    ...


Caused by:

Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Errors were encountered when initialising the specified MetaData. See the nested exceptions for details
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:892)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:794)
    at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.initialisePMF(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:488)
    ...

Caused by:

Found Meta-Data for class com.aspect.todo.model.Task but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Found Meta-Data for class com.aspect.todo.model.Task but this class is not enhanced!! Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseClassMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2225)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:2176)
    at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.initialiseFileMetaDataForUse(MetaDataManager.java:881)
    ...
```

The weird thing is when I start with these sections commented out, compile and run and then activate only Section 2 and rerun it works fine. If close and reopen Eclipse try again the error occurs again.

NOTE: Datanucleus JDO/JPA version: v1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Found Meta-Data for class com.aspect.todo.model.Task but this class is not enhanced!!
Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.
```

The fact is that the classes are **not enhanced** at runtime and you have to find a way to enhance them prior to runtime that works for your environment ... Maven, Ant, command-line, DataNucleus Eclipse plugin, or GAE Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Under Project Properties > Google > App Engine > ORM, I explicitly listed my classes above (despite there is /src folder, which includes them already). Still the same problem.

Comment: so you're using the GAE Eclipse plugin (supported only by Google, try their google group), and as I said there are many other options. Try one of the others

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ANT then add the below lines in your build.xml before `</project>` tag close

```
<target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile"
  description="Performs JDO enhancement on compiled data classes.">
<enhance_war war="war" />
```

And give the following command when build the ant "`ant datanucleusenhance runserver`"

Hope this is useful, it took me a while to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your GAE SDK, it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Found Meta-Data for class com.aspect.todo.model.Task but this class is not enhanced!!
>   Please enhance the class before running DataNucleus.

I'll show here a way to enhance classes in Gradle environment. Use the following configuration.

- Dependencies:

  ```
  dependencies {
      appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:<version>'
      compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:<version>'
      compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:<version>'  // or datanucleus-api-jdo
      /* other dependencies */
  }
  ```
- Plugin:
  *(for gradle-appengine-plugin version 1.9.5 or higher)*

  ```
  appengine {
      enhancer {
          version = "v2"
          api = "jpa"  // or "jdo"
          enhanceOnBuild = true
      }
      /*...*/
  }
  ```

  *(for older versions of gradle-appengine-plugin)*

  ```
  appengine {
      enhancerVersion = "v2"
  }
  ```

  To make enhance run automatically before creating the war in your build.gradle file:

  ```
  war.dependsOn appengineEnhance
  ```

If you have problems executing task `:appengineEnhance`, try to run it with `--stacktrace` (to view the stacktrace) or `--info` (to find the location of the error log file) options.