# Datanucleus enhance using Maven in GAE, Build Failure

Tags: java, maven, jpa, datanucleus

I referred to article as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658809/google-app-engine-entity-relationship-annotations-end-up-http-500) which defines how to enhance a class for data nucleus. I am trying to do the same using Maven but keep on getting build failure

```
DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.2.7) for API "JPA" using JRE "1.7"
DataNucleus Enhancer : Classpath
>>  E:\DevTools\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.2.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.262s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 27 22:41:16 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/227M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.2.0-m2:enhance (default) on project rho_v1.0: Error executing DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.en
hancer.DataNucleusEnhancer: InvocationTargetException: org.datanucleus.metadata.AbstractMemberMetaData.setPersistenceModifier(Ljava/lang/String;)V -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My POM file is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.sis.rho</groupId>
    <artifactId>rho_v1.0</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <appengine.target.version>1.8.3</appengine.target.version>
        <datanucleus-core.version>3.2.7</datanucleus-core.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Struts 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Struts 2 + Spring plugins -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javax persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus-core.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-release</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- struts 2 velocity dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <jvmFlags>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
                        <jvmFlag>-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=y</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags>
                    <disableUpdateCheck>true</disableUpdateCheck>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0-m2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <fork>false</fork>
                    <persistenceUnitName>transactions-optional</persistenceUnitName>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone please help me understand what does that error means and how to avoid that error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does JPA require enhancement too ?

Comment: when i dont add the datanucleus maven plugin for enhancement my build is successfull but i get error while creating `EntityManagerFactory` **"Found Meta-Data for class com.sis.rho.LoginBean but this class is not enhanced!!"**

Comment: use inconsistent versions of (datanucleus) jars and that's what you get

Comment: @DataNucleus, I've learned what you have just said in a VERY hard way. You can only imagine the pain I experienced trying to figure out what's wrong, to find out eventually that I'm deploying on on older datanucleus version.
Don't you think that this error message needs to be more specific ? You'll be saving years of lives :)

Comment: "This error message" comes from a compiler/runtime. How exactly do you think DataNucleus is involved in that process? We publish zips of consistent jars, so its up to the user to actually use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since when has GAE supported DN 3.2.x ? https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility

Comment: thanks it worked after changing the **maven-datanucleus-plugin** version to **3.1.3** :)